# is javascript dynamic content adequate security against script kiddies?

Tags: javascript, security

on a site the user can enter an email account to gain access.  do not want this to be hacked by script kitties.

the input items are generated by javascript and posted via ajax.  do I need things like fuzzy word matches in this environment?

Comment: Aww. But Script Kitties are cute ;)

Comment: @Yacoby - They stink more than normal kitties. Plus they gang up and bully poor helpless dogs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you give some user the possibility to input something, every time your application expects some data from the users, those data can be forged.

No matter how your form is built : your webserver espects some data ; those form and data can be forged/faked ; so, you must be prepared for anything that could be sent to your application.

Still, you can add some levels of security, using, for example :

- [HTTPS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTTP_Secure) so communications cannot be listened to
- A [nonce](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) in your form, to make things harder when it comes to forging forms

Comment: Not only that, but it can also be modified (rather than forged), eg; you get valid user credentials from the wrong person (man-in-the-middle attacks for example).

Comment: thanks.  adding nonce.  unfortunately no https, but adding some mild encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean adequate security against someone writing a script to fish for for valid e-mails using a brute-force style attack?  If so then no, your presumption that "script kiddies" are incapable of either scripting a full-fledged browser instance that can execute your JavaScript content or determining what URL your AJAX ultimately submits to and then forging requests is false.

If you want to protect against these kinds of attacks, then the only effective way to do so is to add code on the server side.  For instance, you could track the number of incorrect access attempts posted per IP address, and block requests (for like an hour or so) from any IP that posts more than, say, 10 invalid requests in a 5-minute time span.  Then you are reasonably safe against this kind of attack until you come across someone with a million-IP bot-net and a grudge against your site.

Another form of protection is to send some random code from the server to the client that gets submitted back with the form (for instance, as a hidden field), and code the server so that ignores any form submits that do not include this code.  This solution works best if you have some way of verifying that the user is trustworthy *before* you display the form (so it's not really useful in the context of a login form, but it could help secure any post-login forms that you may have).  Otherwise it is not too hard for an attacker to compose a script that just grabs a code from your server, and includes it in a forged request.

Comment: thanks - adding ip checking for multiple submissions.  if a bot-net inveighs against me I'm already dead.  random code, nonce above, being done.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript + Ajax forms are just a more fancy means of forms. It's still a request with post/get data so same security measures should be undertaken as per normal HTML form.

Wether you use Ajax or basic HTTP requests, don't send back data you don't want users to see either way. Don't offer services or functionality by means of JavaScript/Ajax you wouldn't offer by means of basic HTTP requests.

Script injection does not need an JavaScript/Ajax vulnerabilities, it just needs unsecure backend code that doesn't catch and eliminate code injections.